# How to identify correct email to update proper database record?

Tags: php, mysql, email, cakephp, imap

Using PHP, I am making an application similar to an online concierge service.  I have a page displaying a form asking the user what he would like me to do.  When the user completes the form, the information is saved into a database and also the user is sent an email saying: "Thank you for recently submitting: (whatever he just submitted)."  The user will (hopefully) be submitting this same form many times each month.

I would like to have the user have the ability to reply to my automated email with new information, and then that new information update the correct database record.

**Problem: How do I get that new information to update the correct database record?**

For example, lets say User 'John' submits that form twice today.  First he requests me to make him dinner reservations at Chili's, and second he requests me to book him some airline tickets to NYC.  John would receive 2 emails from the site thanking him for his requests.  Lets say later today John changes his mind and decides he wants to go to Applebees instead.  I would like him to be able to reply to the FIRST email stating his change.  I would then like that information appended to the correct record in the Database.  **How do I make a connection between the information in the Database record and the email?**

I was thinking as a possible solution I could include the Database's record ID number in the subject line of the email, like:  "Thank you for your recent request #428." and then I could grab that number 428 and update record number 428 in the database.  But I think this might confuse the user if he sees this number popping up out of no where.

I am looking for something similar to using a hidden input like you can do in Form's and processing POST data.

BTW: I am using CakePHP 2.1.x and am downloading my emails using IMAP.  But the answer is probably not CakePHP specific.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Providing an ID to every record seems to be the best solution as you can isolate every record in the DB

Comment: LISTSERV software accomplishes this with a per-message "email address" proxy. This also somewhat helps with impersonation (since the email address you provided to the "user"/client is the key (hopefully only sent to the one account). I would suggest not eradicating the data with a new email, as well, and add a superseding record instead (in case of spoofing).

Comment: You can also look at how JIRA works, since it allows both accounts to be created automatically and issues to be created from email. You don't need to login, of course, to reply to the email, which goes back to the system through a common "reply@" address and specifies an "issue identifier" in the subject used to determine the related issue (after created). This looks like `[JIRA] (PRJ-32) My request subject`, which you can then easily pull with a regex.

Comment: Here's a JIRA plugin, as well, that demonstrates how to send an email to it's handler with fields that are "harvestable", including in CVS format: [JIRA Extensible Mail Handler](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JEMH/JEMH+Home)

Comment: @Jared Thanks for those suggestions.  I am looking at LISTSERV and JIRA right now.

Comment: No problem. It's an interesting question. I would stick with a well-tested email parsing script on top of whatever you build, as well. See the page for [JEMH Directives](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JEMH/JEMH+Directives), which is what Andy calls the field handlers, which should give you some good pointers on how to proceed with a custom script if you need to.

Comment: Also, track the code you send and invalidate it when it's been used or if you have another issue (maybe even time it out after a couple of weeks?). If you do that, bounce the email back with a message about what went wrong and allow them to resubmit the bounce message from the email account (since it can happen someone hits reply to the same email more than once, but you want to prevent it from automatically processing it). And identical resubmissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the usual way of doing it. It's often coupled with unique Reply-To and Sender addresses to add even more security and make it possible to track bounces.

It's pretty safe (why would anybody change the subject line?) but you should still make sure that only the correct sender address can do amendments, otherwise malicious users can just change the number and post stuff to whatever tickets they like.

It's easy for the user. The thing I would change is the wording of the subject, for two reasons:

1. The request number is a technical number and should not be part of a sentence (in my opinion).
2. If you are able to create a more telling subject line so that users can see which of the two mails are for which type of service, it would be much easier for the user to find and answer to the correct one of the two. Even if it's just a very generic category name that distinguishes them it may prove useful to many users.

With this in mind, a great subject line could be:

> Dinner booking request - Automatic confirmation (#428)

Comment: I think the more complicated problem is the "email as a data submission form". Here's how the JIRA JEMH plugin allows you to [handle the formatting](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JEMH/Example+JEMH+eMails), if you can get the client to manage to follow it somehow with possibly little direction.

Comment: I think I would personally make use of a unique email address for each user. It's quite easy to spoof the email from address so using a unique and non-identifiable email address would solve this problem. You could use SPF but that will only ensure that someone from the senders domain is allowed to send the email.

Comment: Steve, a nice thing with showing the "ticket id" is that the user can refer to it if they call or send a separate e-mail. I have worked as a support technician and found that very useful. Using the reply address for the technical side and the ticket id for the social side, maybe?